# Randomly choosing preexisting nodes in tikz-pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, random

### Introduction

I am trying to produce a figure illustrating multiple generations of a population in a  version of the Wright-Fisher model. In this population generations are non-overlapping, each generation has the same number of individuals and each individuals has two parents chosen **randomly** from the previous generation.
This is often represented with nodes on a graph with each generation on the same horizontal line and links between nodes symbolizing heredity between individuals, as following:

[image: Wright-Fisher Population Model]
<sub>(source: [culturemath.ens.fr](https://culturemath.ens.fr/articles-ens/mallein11/images/wright-fisher.jpg))</sub>

### The problem

I already have a functioning code to generate the nodes representing the individuals for multiple generations, but I cannot find a way of making each node choose randomly two nodes in the previous row, corresponding to the previous generation.
My rationale for this was to have each node at a position x of a generation, for a fixed y:

```
 (\x\yi)
```

draw his *parents* randomly from the previous generation / row of nodes, corresponding to yi+1, by generating a number between 0 and 9:

```
 (\pgfmathparse{random(10)}\pgfmathresult-1 , \yi+1)
```

### My code

Here is the code I currently have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumitem}
\usepackage{lcg,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{phv}

\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=red!40,minimum       size=20}]   

  \foreach \x in {0,...,9}
      \foreach \y in {0,...,9}
          \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {}; 

  \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,9}
      \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {0,...,9}
          \draw (\x\yi)--(\pgfmathparse{random(10)}\pgfmathresult-1\yi+1) (\x\yi)--(\pgfmathparse{random(10)}\pgfmathresult-1\yi+1);
        
        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Results

Compliling the above I obtain the following error message from sharelatex.com:

```
 Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 29.

 <inserted text> 
            \fi 
 <*> main.tex
        
 The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
 This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
 the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

 ! Emergency stop.
 <*> main.tex
        
 *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

Maybe the label for nodes in latex is expecting text format and not a number as generated by `\pgfmathparse`.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 5):

The node name can be a macro but it has to expand to a node name.  However, `\pgfmathparse` is not expandable which leads to this rather cryptic error.  You can perform the `\pgfmathparse` action right before the coordinate is evaluated using `\pgfextra`.

It also doesn't make an awful lot of sense to `count` entries in a list of consecutive integers.  I replaced that by a solution using `remember`.

Node names which only contain numbers are likely to blow things up, especially when decimals are involved.  To given you at least some kind of protection I prefixed all nodes with `n`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=red!40,minimum size=20}]   

  \foreach \x in {0,...,9}
      \foreach \y in {0,...,9}
          \node [darkstyle]  (n\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {}; 

  % Set the seed for deterministic random connections
  \pgfmathsetseed{42}
  \foreach \y [remember=\y as \lasty (initially 0)] in {1,...,9}
      \foreach \x in {0,...,9} {
          \draw (n\x\lasty) \pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{random(0,9)}} -- (n\pgfmathresult\y);
          \draw (n\x\lasty) \pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{random(0,9)}} -- (n\pgfmathresult\y);
      }


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot To obtain a picture as in the question one would definitely have to “tag” the spheres with their categories (apparently they are not allowed to mix) and then enforce the single-parent-multiple-child rule on top of that, but at this point it might be easier to just draw the whole thing by hand.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree. That's why I have erased my earlier comment long time ago. (BTW, for some reason the @marmot did not ping me, perhaps because my comments were already erased.)

Comment: Should everything child have two *different* parents? I can see this neither in the codes nor in the pictures. For example the child in the last row and third column in the picture above seems to have only the node in the sixth column of the previous row as "parent".

Comment: @JensSchwaiger It has two *randomly chosen* parents.  Those two random parents can also be one and the same.

Comment: Ok. I suppose, the solution to the other question, namely two different parents, would be more complicated, as one should have to choose two different nodes at random.